# How to tell amperage of a circuit breaker in basement? Also... adding a dedicated line for Treadmill?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm not doing any of this work myself! I have ZERO electrical work background. I'm asking this to better educate myself so I can understand what needs to be done.

We bought a townhouse recently, it's only 3 years old (we're the second owners). Very new and up-to-date

We put a treadmill in the back room of the ground level floor (which has the door to our garage, a small room, a half-bathroom, and a small hallway with a few lights).

The treadmill is blowing the fuse... the whole downstairs floor & garage go out. It didn't happen right away... we used it a handful of times, then one day out of nowhere half hour in it blew. Now it'll blow when we first turn it on, or 5 minutes in. *We tried lubricating the belt to make sure it wasn't the treadmill and nothing worked. It did not do this in the upstairs bedroom of our old place, which was a much older house.

We've left it alone and have been calling electricians, but they were all very booked over the holidays so we are finally getting one to come out this weekend.

My questions are:

1. Is this normal?? Should such a new house be having circuit breaker issues with trying to support a treadmill? Did we get screwed on the electrical profile of our home?
2. Is there a way to tell the amperage of the circuit breaker for the downstairs floor? I found that treadmills average 10 - 12 amps
3. We plan on asking the electrician to give us an estimate to run a dedicated line for the treadmill. Is this the right approach?

Comment: What else is on the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is going out the circuit is overloaded. Standard breakers are inverse time trip this means if right at the max level usually printed on the handle (15 or 20) amps the circuit may hold for 10 minutes before tripping but if a short were to happen it would trip immediately. If you turn a light or 2 off you may be able to use the treadmill. Other things like freezes on the same circuit can cause the circuit to trip quicker if running at the same time as the treadmill. It is possible your old home had a 20 amp circuit and or was lightly loaded so no problem, now if a 15 amp circuit and  a heavy load the breaker is doing its job of protecting the wiring.  A new branch circuit would be a good path forward and possibly having the garage on its own circuit for the time you may want to run a power tool the same thing will happen there.